# Loop Scala both ways depending on parameters

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop

I am currently working on some function that takes in two numbers in Scala (I have only worked with Scala once in the past for a few weeks).

I need to iterate a loop between two numbers; `a` and `b`.

So `if a = 0, b = 10`, I want to loop from `0 to 10`, `if a = 10, b = 0`, I wants to loop from `10 to 0`.

I want to do this in the most efficient way, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```scala
(a to b by (if (a < b) 1 else -1)).foreach { x => ??? }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, wasn't entirely sure how to use the `.foreach { x => ??? }` so I just implemented the `by (if (a < b) 1 else -1)` into my existing loop.

Comment: `if (a < b) 1 else -1` can be written `(b-a).sign` in Scala 3.